# How to create an API in Java to change the password of a Unix user?

Tags: java, unix

I am new to Unix environment,

What I have to do is to create an API to change the password of a user having an Unix environment.

Comment: Have you written any code so far? If so, post what you've done so we can better assist you.

Comment: i have search for the code to be implemented as i have never executed a java code in the Unix environment.

So i am searching for that also.
So far i have searched 


ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myshellScript.sh", "myArg1", "myArg2");
   Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
   env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
   env.remove("OTHERVAR");
   env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
   pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
   Process p = pb.start();


now i am trying to get the meaning of the variables like myarg1,var,othervar etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'll need to work with 'passwd' unix command which is intended for changing the password.

You'll need to call this command from java by using the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

or the older API [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

Now you'll also need to intercept the output of the passwd command if you want to run it interactively (like using some ui to enter the actual password and so on). In this case I would suggest you to read [This article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1)

You may consider also using some kind of predefined shell script that will allow to change the password non interactively. In this case you'll just invoke the script and it will do all the work.

Hope this helps

Comment: i have search for the code to be implemented as i have never executed a java code in the Unix environment.

So i am searching for that also.
So far i have searched 


ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myshellScript.sh", "myArg1", "myArg2");
   Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
   env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
   env.remove("OTHERVAR");
   env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
   pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
   Process p = pb.start();

Answer (score 2):

Be really careful when dealing with passwords so there is no leak. Use [exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29%5d) to invoke the system command (typically `passwd`)

Answer (score 1):

One hint. After you invoke the `passwd` command, you need to print password 2 times on stdout when system will ask for it.

To see how read form stdin after invoking `exec()` check:
http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/io/javazine.html